# How to use SQLiteBlob when rowId is not an integer?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, asp.net-core, blob

How can SQLLiteBlob be used oder replace by another method when the rowId is a string?
Here the sample code.

```
    public void WriteContent(Stream contentStream, string table, string rowId)
    {
        // ToDo : Find Solution for Writing to Blob as RowId is no more an integer
        using var writeStream = new SqliteBlob(this.executionContext.GetConnection(), table, ColumnName, rowId);
        contentStream.CopyTo(writeStream);
    }
```

Alternative way to use the method with a string or an alternative way to implement.

Comment: Are you confusing RowID with Primary Key perhaps? A ROWID is always a 64-bit integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better make it integer.
Rowid can only be integer. If not, means you are using table"without rowid" .
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid

Without rowid, Blob I/O wouldn't work.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/blob-io
https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/blob_open.html
[image]